# How to transpose a single column in BigQuery without specifying all the values in the column?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table of the following type:

```
col_A col_B col_C col_D
 1     ab    cd    val1
 2     cd    ef    val2
 2     cd    ef    val3
 3     ab    bc    val4
```

What I would like to do is something of the following:

```
col_A col_B col_C val1 val2 val3 val4
 1     ab    cd    1    0    0    0
 2     cd    ef    0    1    1    0
 3     ab    bc    0    0    0    1
```

Basically transpose col_4 such that there is a column for every entry in it, and a value of 1 indicates that the value is present in the row, and value of 0 indicates that it isn't present in the row.

The challenge is that I do not know all the values that can come in col_4, so I need to be able to create such a view without creating case statements specific to certain values in col_4 to create new columns. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is helpful: You said you don't know what values in `col_D` in advance, so it will be needed to create a pivot query dynamically using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE sample AS
SELECT * FROM UNNEST([STRUCT
  (1 AS col_A, 'ab' AS col_B, 'cd' AS col_C, 'val1' AS col_D),
  (2, 'cd', 'ef', 'val2'),
  (2, 'cd', 'ef', 'val3'),
  (3, 'ab', 'bc', 'val4')
]);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  SELECT * FROM sample PIVOT (COUNT(col_A) FOR col_D IN ('%s'));
""", ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT col_D FROM sample ORDER BY 1), "','"));
```

output:

[image]

If you want a exact same result in your question, try this instead of previous query.

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT col_A AS col, * FROM sample)
   PIVOT (COUNT(col) FOR col_D IN ('%s')) 
   ORDER BY 1;
""", ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT col_D FROM sample ORDER BY 1), "','"));
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer! Do you know of a way to save the results of this query in a view? I'd like to keep updating a single table source that I can pull into my BI tool and not have to run this query every time

Comment: Unfortunately, You can't make a dynamic sql as a view.

Answer (score 1):

or just simply

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  SELECT * FROM sample PIVOT (COUNT(*) FOR col_D IN ('%s'));
""", ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT col_D FROM sample ORDER BY 1), "','"));
```

with output

[image]

Comment: thanks for the comment! Is there any way I can save this query as a view?

Comment: unfortunately, No!